# java thread waiting for dead process to finish

Tags: java, multithreading, process

I wrote a java class in order to perform multithreaded tasks, each task running an external process.
The process is in charge of converting ".chp" files into ".txt" files.  It is written in C.

This process breaks at one point because it disappears when looking at a "top" in my terminal (probably due to a corrupted chp file).  The problem is that the process in my java thread does not return.  The "process.waitFor()" seems to go on forever (at least 'til the 12 hours I specified for the ExecutorService.

Am I doing something wrong (not catching an exception?)?
I tried setting a class variable of type String in MyThread and putting an error message in place of throwing a new RuntimeException, then print the String at the end of the main, but the thread code doesn't reach to this point.  It still gets stuck at the waitFor().

Shouldn't the process terminate once the C program has failed?

The program prints on the terminal (cf: MyThread):

```
A
B
C
```

main:

```
String pathToBin = "/path/to/bin";
List<MyThread> threadList = new ArrayList<MyThread>();

for (File f : folderList) {
    File[] chpFilesInFolder = f.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            if (name.endsWith(".chp")){
                 return true;
            }else{
                 return false;
            }
        }
    });
    File chpFile = writeChpFiles(chpFilesInFolder);
    String[] cmd = {pathToBin, "--arg1", chpFile, "--out-dir", outputFolder};
    MyThread t = new MyThread(cmd, f, chpFilesInFolder);
    threadList.add(t);
}

ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
for(MyThread th : threadList){
    threadExecutor.execute(th);
}
threadExecutor.shutdown();

try {
    threadExecutor.awaitTermination(12, TimeUnit.HOURS);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

MyThread:

```
class MyThread extends Thread{
    private String[] cmd;
    private File chpFolder;
    private File[] chpFilesInFolder;

    public MyThread(String[] cmd, File chpFolder, File[] chpFilesInFolder){
        this.cmd = cmd;
        this.chpFolder = chpFolder;
        this.chpFilesInFolder = chpFilesInFolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Process process = null;
        try{
            System.err.println("A ");
            ProcessBuilder procBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
            procBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);

            System.err.println("B");
            process = procBuilder.start();

            System.err.println("C");
            process.waitFor();

            System.err.println("D");
            if(process.exitValue()!=0) System.err.println("ERROR !"+process.exitValue());

            System.err.println("E");
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Throwable e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            System.err.println("F");
            if(process!=null) {try { process.destroy();} catch(Exception err) {err.printStackTrace();}}
        }

        File[] txtFilesInFolder = chpFolder.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                if (name.endsWith(".chp.txt")){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

        if (txtFilesInFolder.length==chpFilesInFolder.length){
            for (File chp : chpFilesInFolder) {
                chp.delete();
            }
            File logFile = new File(chpFolder, "apt-chp-to-txt.log");
               if (logFile.exists()){
                   logFile.delete();
               }
        }else{
            throw new RuntimeException("CHPs have not all been transformed to TXT in "+chpFolder.getAbsolutePath());
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible that your C program is producing output on stdout? If so, you need to read Process.getOutputStream() before Process.waitFor() returns - see https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4254231

Alternatively, call your C program that a shell script that redirects stdout.

You can use the jstack command to confirm that the thread is indeed blocked at Process.waitFor().

Comment: Haven't tested yet, quite hard to reproduce the case, but it makes a lot of sense if that "bug" (if it really is one) is still something we can experience today (your link is quite old ;) ).

Comment: It works !!  You indeed have to consume the output of the program for the waitFor() to return !!

Answer (score 0):

You could have the main thread wait for a reasonable amount of time and then call some method on the `MyThread` class to kill the started process, thus causing the thread to finish.

Comment: The thing is I don't really know how much time each thread will take to run.  For as long as a thread is taking a place in the ExecutorService (4 threads max), another can't start, which is quite annoying...  Furthermore, I would kike to understand why the process doesn't return when the external program breaks !

Comment: @Eric: Well you should have some kind of fail-safe mechanism in case the process never terminates, like a timeout after which you kill the process.

Comment: There is a timeout for the ExecutorService which garantees that the program will finally end.  Nevertheless the thread can return in 5 minutes or last for many hours.  If a process breaks after 2 minutes, even if I set a timeout after, let's say, 5 hours, it will be 5 hours of a dead process taking a place in my Executor...  Not really satisfying !!

Comment: But can't you just wait like 10 seconds with a `Thread.sleep` in the main thread after starting all the threads and then call a method on each thread that kills the process if it's not finished yet?

Comment: How will I know if the process should be killed or not?  If the process stays in the waitFor() mode, I guess that it is still alive, not matter if the C program has broken or not...  It is this point that I don't understand.  How can the process live if the underlying program breaks??

Comment: Well it's pretty simple to know. If after 10 seconds the thread's run method has not returned, then the process must still be alive. You can check if a thread is alive with `Thread.isAlive()`. For all threads that are still alive, call a method that executes `process.destroy()`. As for the process not dying, without the actual code of the C program we cannot know.

Comment: All my threads are supposed to stay alive for much longer than 10 seconds.  I didn't show the end of the MyTread class but many steps are to be executed after the process return.  I have no way to know if the thread is still alive and waiting for the C program to finish, or if the thread is still alive when the C program breaks because the process doesn't return in this last case.  I guess you are right, without modifying the C program, I cannot do anything.  I still find it very strange that the process still waits when the C program breaks...  I expected it to quit the waitFor() mode...

Comment: Ok, but you can for example set a boolean flag after the call to `waitFor()` returns. Then if the flag is set it means the process has finished and you leave the thread alone. Otherwise, if the flag is still not set it means the process is still running so you can kill it. I could try to update the answer with some sample code if you want.

Comment: If the flag is not set, it only means that the process is still running !!  Once again, I have no way to know if it is waiting because the C program is not finished, or if it is waiting even though the C program has broken.  I do not want to kill a process that is simply waiting because the C program is not finished !! And I do need to wait for the process to finish because after the C program has run (normal condition) I need to execute a few more steps.  In normal condition, the C program can run for a long time (few hours).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7752/discussion-between-eric-and-tudor)

Answer (score 0):

If I understad correctly, your Java threads remain waiting after the C program crashes.

Make the spawned C process send heart beats. You can do this even by printing sth to console (or inserting in a table) and have the Java thread every so often wake up and check the heartbeat. If it's not there, assume the C process died and terminate the thread.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "printing sth" !  If you mean modifying the C program, that is not possible.  I do not have the required skills for that and it's a pretty big program.

Comment: ya I mean modifying it to print something or send sth a heartbeat to a db so the Java side can check it

Answer (score 0):

as often I would suggest to use a more robust and professional point of view while using a messsaging solution to make your C program interact with your Java application, it  will be easy and clean to avoid those non daemon threads waiting for ever because of the crash of your C application... now all brokers have a STOMP interface which is pretty cool for any kind of application to invoke (just use any Http library), broker configuration will enable to restart non finished jobs, to put some timeouts and so one..Even if JMS does not support request and response it's quite easy to implement such paradigm....

HTH
Jerome

Comment: As far as I understand your answer, you're talking about a web application. But my java program is a standalone cmd-line application.

Answer (score 0):

Launching external processes in Java can get a little bit tricky. I usually try to avoid them as you'll have to deal with different error codes and some terminal madness. I recommend you use specialized libraries such as commons-exec (http://commons.apache.org/exec/)